# Locking joints and frame construction

Tags: joining, frame

I'm designing a large light art project and I've been trying to find kits that could essentially make lattice-like structures. For example how stages and cranes have lattice structures. The idea would be similar to wire frame floats for parades, but with adjustable locking joints and plastic or aluminum pipes.

The idea would be similar to a locking Hirth joint, but would also be universal, so I could assemble the pipes in any direction and lock them. Doesn't have to be Hirth though.
[image]

The final structure would be similar to this, but again fully adjustable and able to make different types of latticed structures.

[image]

Does anything like this exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the scaffolding clamps - both fixed and pin- jointed.

Comment: Oh wow that's awesome. I've never heard of those...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sketch below shows the reason why it is not possible to change the position of a locked lattice frame unless to find ways to accommodate the geometry changes at every connected joint.

[image]

Comment: Good point. I think you pointed out what I was wondering; if there is a universal locking joint. The hirth design had appeal because it has a high degree of torque, whereas a locking ball joint could always come loose.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the point I wanted to convey - in changing the direction of the truss frame, the length of the member will change, and the rigid member and link are not capable of following the change.

Comment: Oh yes, I see now.